# Java. Spell check content in a JTextPane, against a dictionary as a file

Tags: java

I am attempting to write a spell-checker for a self-made notepad on Java. I have a dictionary as a file, and want to spell check the content on the JTextPane. Content of both the file and JTextPane have been stored in a array. The problem is that all the words on the JTextPane appear wrong. Any help is much appreciated!

This is the code I have:

```
void checkspell(){

    String filename = "ordliste.txt";
    String split = String.valueOf(filename.split(" "));
    String linje = new String();
    ArrayList ord_array = new ArrayList();
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        if (!input.ready()) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        while ((linje = input.readLine()) != null) {
            ord_array.add(linje);
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int sz = ord_array.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        //System.out.println(ord_array.get(i).toString().toLowerCase());
    }

    //setter pane content in arraylist
    String linje3=Controller.mittVindu.pane.getText();
    String linje2=null;
    pane_array.add(linje3);

    //for spell-check

        for (int i = 0; i < pane_array.size(); i++) { // Loop that checks words
            if (ord_array.contains(pane_array.get(i))) {
                Color green_color = Color.green;
                String text1 = null;
                StyleContext sc1 = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
                AttributeSet attr1 = sc1.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, green_color);

                int len1 = Controller.mittVindu.pane.getDocument().getLength();
                Controller.mittVindu.pane.setCaretPosition(len1);
                Controller.mittVindu.pane.setCharacterAttributes(attr1, false);
                Controller.mittVindu.pane.replaceSelection(linje3);
                System.out.println("finnes");
            } else {
                Color red_color = Color.red;
                String text1 = null;
                StyleContext sc1 = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
                AttributeSet attr1 = sc1.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, red_color);

                int len1 = Controller.mittVindu.pane.getDocument().getLength();
                Controller.mittVindu.pane.setCaretPosition(len1);
                Controller.mittVindu.pane.setCharacterAttributes(attr1, false);
                Controller.mittVindu.pane.replaceSelection(linje3);
                System.out.println("finnes ikke");
            }
        } }
```

Comment: Looks like `pane_array` contains the entire text as a single string. I did not see you split it up anywhere.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I tried splitting pane_array, with linje3.split(" ");            unfortunately, that did not solve my problem. The code works if I test only one word, however not if I test a sentence or more.

Comment: What error information did you get?

Comment: I get no error information. The problem is what i write in JTextPane is all marked as wrongly spelled, even though that it is spellec correctly,